# Migra una pagina de Joomla a WordPress en el Dominio

Tags: wordpress, joomla3

Tengo un cliente que quiere que le pase la web que tiene elaborada con Joomla a WordPress pero conservando toda la información que tiene en ella y al mismo dominio, lo que que no se es como se puede hacer porque si fuera de un dominio a otro con un plungin lo puedo hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un plugin llamado FG Joomla to WordPress. Con ese plugin puedes migrar todo sin perder información, el problema es que tendrás que hacer muchos cambios.

Comment: gracias ya me habían comentado de ese plungin pero no sabia que se podía migrar al mismo dominio pensé que era nada mas para migrar a otro hosting

Answer (score 0):

Otra idea que yo he empleado (si la página no es demasiado compleja), es utilizar httrack https://www.httrack.com

Con este programa te bajas el html del sitio completo y luego lo montas en wordpress.

Desgraciadamente, no funcionará en caso de que necesites migrar un woocommerce p.ej. pero sí en el caso de que tu cliente tenga 4 páginas (digamos) y un montón de fotos.

El truco estará en como configures el programa HTTrack